# php database - is_int returns false always

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, integer

I have written a simple sql query and [is_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) returns alway false. why?

**mysql query**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE email = 'mail@example.com' LIMIT 1"; 
$data = $db->query($sql); 
# output: php array like $data[0]['id'];
```

**php if**

```
if( is_int($data[0]['id'] ){
  print 1;
}else{
  print 0;
}
```

// edit
var_dump print this:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(6) "admin" }
```

Why is 'id' a string and not a integer?

Comment: what is your id field in the DB? an integer or a varchar?

Comment: why do you need of is_int?

Comment: display the output of `var_dump($data)`

Comment: how we fetch the data from database i mean a single row,a array or an object????

Comment: here is the Problem I think:
 array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(6) "admin" }

@saty: mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: I'm pretty sure that everything you get back from a database, are strings, but I cannot find any references. What database API are you using, PDO, mysqli, etc.? By the way, you could use `is_numeric` instead.

Comment: I use [mysql-functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) and now I use this [isInteger](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-int.php#82857)

Comment: Why do you need to test the type? Since the MySQL datatype is `INT`, it has to be a string containing an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can an "id" be not an integer?

If you want to check the value:

```
<?php
function is_int_val($val) {
    return $val == (string)((int)$val);
}
echo (is_int_val(33) ? "true" : "false")."\n"; // returns true
echo (is_int_val("33") ? "true" : "false")."\n"; // returns true
echo (is_int_val("33.0") ? "true" : "false")."\n"; // returns true
echo (is_int_val("a33") ? "true" : "false")."\n"; // returns false
echo (is_int_val("33a") ? "true" : "false")."\n"; // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the type of your variable is string.
In your case is a good idea to use [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

If you expect to have some float values you may use [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) as well:

```
if( is_numeric($data[0]['id']) && !is_float($data[0]['id']) ){
  print 1;
}else{
  print 0;
}
```

Comment: Floats are numeric, too

Answer (score 0):

In case of string value `is_int()` always return false.

```
is_int('23') = bool(false)
```

and according to comments you have ID as string

```
array(2) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["username"]=> string(6) "admin" 
}
```

So its always return false

Do it like :

```
if( is_array($data) && $data[0]['id'] > 0 ) {
    print 1;
} 
else print 0;
```